# Why does my image not fill the whole canvas' width?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want my canvas to fill the whole screen width. But it is not working correctly.

```js
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-test");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image()
img.src = "../img/runningPersonAnimation/Komp 2_00020.png";
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
img.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas-test"></canvas>
```

As intended, my canvas fills the whole screen. Why is that not the case with the image?

How it looks at the moment:
[image: example picture]

Comment: What do you want to happen when the img aspect ratio is completely different from the device's aspect ratio? Do you want it to fill the canvas - i.e. get cropped either top/bottom or at the sides depending on what is required to cover the whole canvas? Or do you want the whole image to be visible, centered perhaps either vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

It may be to do with the width of the image. If you were to make it the full width of the canvas it would look very stretched out. Try an image with the same dimensions as the canvas and see what it looks like.

Comment: Yes you are right. My image has a width of 1576px while my screen has a width of 1920px. Is there a way to make to image bigger or do I need to take a bigger image?

Comment: You would need a bigger image. There might be a way to increase the whole size of the image using an image editing software such a photoshop, or perhaps even paint. I would try adding the image to paint for example, extending it from the corners so that it stays in proportion and then once at desired width snipping tool (or lightshot for mac) to get to desired dimensions. Might have a negative affect on the image quality though.

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio of the image is off, but you can use the `background-image:` property in CSS, the picture would look zoomed in though and perhaps a bit pixelated:

```
  background-image: url('../img/yourimg.png');
  background-size: cover; /* this can be changed to percentages, such as  background-size: 50% 50%;*/
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Keep in mind this doesn't hold any semantic value though

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by resizing the image while using drawImage.

js:

```
const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(20);
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
img.onload=function(){
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth * 0.66666666666); 
}
```

By multiplying my window.innerWidth with 0.66666666666 I get to keep my ratio, so the image does not seem stretched.